# Play encrptyed dvd on 12.04

Tags: dvd

I have played dvds on this aspire 5315 using 10.04
I Just upgrade the aspire to 12.04
I have tryied to install the decrpyting libs.
But this command (sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh) does not work.
It returns this error HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found . 
At this point dvd will play but it is all broken up .
It appears all libs are installed.
Hope someone can help I like using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The server that handles those packages is down, likely until next week. If you can't wait then you can get a .deb from deb multimedia

Just download the one for your arch & install with either software-center, gdebi or dpkg from cli

For i386, -

```
cd Downloads && \
wget http://www.deb-multimedia.org/pool/main/libd/libdvdcss/libdvdcss2_1.3.0-dmo1_i386.deb
```

For amd64

`cd Downloads && \
wget http://www.deb-multimedia.org/pool/main/libd/libdvdcss/libdvdcss2_1.3.0-dmo1_amd64.deb`

Then r. click on the .deb > choose install action of choice